# accessing a value stored in stack MIPS

Tags: assembly, stack, mips

I want to know that in a single function, when I go to somewhere else by beq or bne a new stack is created or since I'm still inside of a same function my stack is continues ? let me explain my question via an example .
Before test part, I've stroed the content of $t3 into stack and after going test I want to reach it.Is it possible ? Thanks in advance

```
   main:
       addi $sp, $sp, -1
       sb $t3,($sp)       #t3 stores value 1 and I stored it into stack by this line
       beq $t1 $t2 test   #assume it holds


   test:
      lb $t7,($sp)        # now I want to take 1 into $t7 here.Is it possible ??
      addi $sp, $sp, 1
      la $t7,($a0)
      li $v0,4 
      syscall 
      li $v0,10
      syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to call a function, use jump and not branch. Branch is usually for ifs, whiles and such. There are special jump instructions such as `jalr` (jump and link register) specially made for this purpose as it stores the return address in `$ra` (so you can *return* from a function).

As of your question, of course you can access. The stack is just a region of memory. But what you're doing is actually *passing a parameter to a function*. The MIPS ABI states that this should be done through the `$aX` registers and not in stack.

*EDIT*: I see you're confused about the stack. See [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html) for more detailed information about stack in MIPS (in other architectures it's very similar too).

Comment: test is a function you're calling with a parameter. In assembly there is no separate syntax for functions, it's how you use them that makes them functions. Anyway, why don't you just use $t3 value and copy it into $t7? `or $t7, $t3, $t3`

Comment: do I loose my stack when I go to test: label ? I mean I can continue from the same point in stack ?

Comment: No, stack is the same, you can access the stack, but as I said, you don't need the stack for such things as passing parameters in MIPS. Oh and stack is decremented by 4, not by 1.

Comment: its just a naive example to understand stack. My problem is a bit different. I add stack a byte.Even if I add byte should I decrement/increment it 4 ?

Comment: No, you're doing it right, sorry my bad, didn't notice the sb. But actually it's recommended to only push words to the stack.

Comment: my real problem is postfix evaluation. I had my postfix exprassion in a array like 10/1. (/ and . operator 1 and 0 value) and I want to calculate this expression.I think I have to use stack to do that. When I read a value I push it into stack addi `$sp, $sp, -1` `sb $t3,($sp)` and when I get operand I take the last 2 pushed value from stack calculate it and then again push it into stack. How could I do that? I think the code above will do that but It failed

Comment: if you have enough time,could we talk via chat ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40518/discussion-between-eday-and-m0skit0)